# Ember select not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to display a list of names in a select box.

#### Controller

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  selectedName: 'Tom',
  names: ["Yehuda", "Tom"]
});
```

#### Template

```
{{view Ember.Select
  content=names
  value=selectedName
}}
```

But the select box is coming up empty, here is a jsbin showing the issue: [JSBin link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cifere/2/edit)

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You should rename App.ApplicationController to App.IndexController since you located on index route for your jsbin example. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/zoxexezi/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I moved your code inside of:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
```

To inside of the first script tag, and it worked.  I think to get the code to work the way you have it you need to specify the controller to be Index Controller to match the Route, like so:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  selectedName: 'Tom',
  names: ["Yehuda", "Tom"]
});
```